# Recover map from the string representation

Tags: clojure

I have a string which is a representation of a clojure map. Is there an easy way to reconstruct the map from the string?

An example of the string -

```
{:Location {:CountryData {:country_cf 99, :country_code "us", :country "united states"}, :longitude -80.17833, :msa 33100, :dma 528}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `read-string` function:

```
(read-string "{:Location {:CountryData {:country_cf 99, :country_code \"us\", :country \"united states\"}, :longitude -80.17833, :msa 33100, :dma 528}}")
```

Comment: Beware that this function calls the clojure reader which by default allows code evaluation, e.g. `(read-string "{:a #=(+ 1 2)}")` calls the `+` function. To prevent this, bind the global variable [\*read-eval\*](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/*read-eval*) to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting. I've never used clojure, but in Lisp dialects this is done with the `read` function. I'll go out on a limb here and say you can do it in clojure according to http://clojure.org/reader.

So maybe `(with-in-str your-string (read))`?

Comment: brilliant! im kicking myself for not thinking of this!